# A story about a super soldier name Lambda 602

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi, military-sf

I'm looking for a novel where the main character is a super-soldier called Lambda 602 who's just like Master Chief from Halo.

He is transported to fantasy world, where he became a familiar their that he believes that its his commander

Answer (score 2):

This is the web-novel ['Blessed are the Simple'](https://www.reddit.com/r/hfy/wiki/series/blessed_are_the_simple) by naturalpinkflamingo.

> *Blessed are the Simple tells the story of **Lambda Six-Oh-Two**, a human
>   supersoldier unwittingly summoned by the young elf maiden Elenore
>   Redwing. Thrown into a fantasy world of magic, elves, and beast-men,
>   Lambda copes by following his programming, which means following
>   orders and utilizing military force to handle his problems. Meanwhile,
>   Elenore quickly realizes that Lambda is a human war machine whose
>   self-proclaimed mission is to "protect and follow her orders," and
>   must quickly figure out how to deal with a being whose sole purpose is
>   to fight. Follow the adventures of the least-likely familiar and his
>   elven commander as they make friends, battle monsters, and perhaps
>   save the world.*